Signing operations for your tezos node
I'm exploring the world of baking and endorsing on my own tezos node. And, I was planning on using my ledger nano to sign for baking and endorsing operations. Given that these signatures have to be done by physical interaction with the device, how does a node operator sign for all these transactions, occurring at all hours of the day, without being chained to their server? If your goal is not to miss any baking or endorsing opportunities, what options are there that allow you to walk away from the server for things like sleep? How are other node operators achieving such high performance levels?

The ledger baking app is not interactive. It just stays on and signs baking and attestation operations, excluding any other operation like transfer which is the purview of the regular Tezos app.
